# Selenium getAttribute from in between tags?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

That's my source I want to verify with selenium:

```
<tr class="myclass">
    <td class="column" style="width:50%"> Key </td>
    <td style="width:50%"> Value </td>
    <td style="width:50%"> &nbsp; </td>
</tr>
```

I want to verify that he word "Values" is contained there.

Following statement always returns: "Key" instead of "Values"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Key')]]/td")).getText();
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the text of my xpath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='myclass']/td[1]")).getText();
```

all the columns in the table are siblings. If you call them without array it will return the value of first one. Try td[2] if td[1] doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this This way, it will not be dependent on what **position** it is in, just that it exists?

```
//tr/descendant::td[contains(text(), 'Value')]
```

or do a FindElements on:

```
//tr[@class='myclass']/td
```

and then loop through them all, ensuring 'Value' appears.

Answer (score 0):

try using css selector

`driver.findElement(By.cssselector(".myclass > td[style='width:50%']")).getText();`